# Android How to display a list of downloaded files?

Tags: java, android, browser, download, android-webview

I use WebView In my application for downloading files, as shown below:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                    long contentLength) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

How can I display a list of the downloaded files in my application? I would like to have the pattern of the downloaded files page to be similar to the pattern of the page of downloaded files in the standard Android web browser. It would be most convenient to run of my application is that your web browser Android, but the users don’t realize that another application loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at creating an activity that extends a ListActivity

Here is an example:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

or google for something like "android listActivity example" for lots of examples